# I can't update my grub, error below

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I can't seem to update my grub. I have tried the grub customizer and using the install.sh files. When I use the install.sh files I get the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: �GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=: not found
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error so I can actually edit my grub or a workaround?

Comment: What install.sh files are you referring to?  the usual method to update the grub.cfg file is to run sudo update-grub.  Did you delete the /etc/default/grub line beginning with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX?

Comment: I'm referring to the install.sh files that come with the grub theme that I wanted to install. When I run the sudo update-grub command I get the same error about missing that line. Do you know how I can replace it?

Comment: The line should look like GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" but maybe you better post the file /etc/default/grub to see what other unwanted changes were made.